# Why does storing the output of .count() result in all 1's or 0's?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I run loc on to find all values within the loc parameters. Whatever the loc returns gets stored in a variable. I try to use this variable to store it in another dataframe column but it only returns 1's and 0's for the whole column.

How would I get what is being printed to be properly appended to a new dataframe?

I think the .count() has something to do with it, meaning it is changing the value of s4 and s5 when applied to the new dataframe.

```
for name in pros_unique:    
    s4 = df.loc[(df.pros_split == name) & (df.orc_4 == 1)].orc_4.count()
    s5 = df.loc[(df.pros_split == name) & (df.orc_5 == 1)].orc_4.count()

    tots_df['orc_4_totals'] = s4
    tots_df['orc_5_totals'] = s5
    # This prints out in the correct format 
    print(name, s4, s5)
```

Output of print statement:

```
name1 77 22
name2 62 32
name3 43 29
name4 1 1
name5 61 24
```

This is the tots_df dataframe:

````
pros    orc_4_totals    orc_5_totals
0   name1     1        0
1   name2     1        0
2   name3     1        0
3   name4     1        0
4   name5     1        0
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on each loop you assign a single value to the entire column:

```py
   tots_df['orc_4_totals'] = s4    # entire column orc_4_totals = s4!
```

(the same thing for the other column.

It equals all ones then, just because your final loop value fills it with `1`.

You need to insert single values instead, for each row of your target dataframe.
However, because I don't know if your target dataframe `tots_df` has an existing index, I would suggest first saving the values in a list, then assigning them:

```py
orc_4_values = []
orc_5_values = []
for name in pros_unique:
    # perform your checks, then assign using:
    s4 = df.loc[(df.pros_split == name) & (df.orc_4 == 1)].orc_4.count()
    s5 = df.loc[(df.pros_split == name) & (df.orc_5 == 1)].orc_4.count()
    orc_4_values.append(s4)
    orc_5_values.append(s5)

# Add to dataframe after the loop
tots_df['orc_4_totals'] = orc_4_values
tots_df['orc_5_totals'] = orc_5_values
```

Comment: That works great, thank you!